# Insert a dropdownlist inside an article in joomla

Tags: joomla2.5

Thanks and regards.Hello, I'm trying to put a dropdownlist inside an article but I don't know how, could you help me?, any advice. I use joomla 2.5

Comment: As @MONZTAAA describes, it is fairly easy to create a drop down list but is there some action you want associated with an item being selected?

Comment: Yes, I would love when someone choose one ítem, It can appear more information about this item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is insert in your article the HTML code of a drop down list.

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Go to your article and in the editor you will find a button which is a white page with these symbols: <> (Source Code Editor).

Once you click on this you will see your article in HTML format and you can insert here the code given above and edit it your own way.

Hope this helps.